# change header html

Tags: php, get

How would I change something in the header (used in every page)? I was thinking I could do something with GET, but *get* an error when I try.
Basically what I want to do is make a nav bar with the current location.

Comment: Show us what you've got (code) so far?

Comment: Please add much more detail about your situation

Comment: I think this is an absolutely fine question, folks. The guy is just really new and doesn't know how to explain himself. He's trying to set up a simple "breadcrumbs" and nav system - that's it.

Comment: I'm with Alex, +1.. we all have to start somewhere and the question was pretty clear to me

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to set up a system where the title of the page is determined based upon the current URL.

You obviously need to define the mapping between the URL's and the friendly titles somewhere. I recommend doing it in a separate file.

Let's imagine that you have 3 pages today:

- page1.php
- page2.php
- page3.php

I would then add a new page, called navigation.php, and do a require('navigation.php') at the top of every one of your existing pages. Then, inside that navigation.php, I would do this:

```
$mapping = array(
   "page1.php" => "My first page",
   "page2.php" => "My second page",
   "page3.php" => "My third page");

$currentUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Then iterate over the $mapping array and find the key that matches the $currentUrl. Then simply print out the value for that key - it'll be your page title.